# Value not propagated from custom control with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

i have the this Custom Control which includes a select component.
But in my reactive form the value is never propagated.

Can somebody help me with that?

My custom control:

```
const SOME_SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => SomeSelectComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'some-select',
  template: `
  <select class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>Bitte wählen sie einen Eintrag aus aus</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of optionItems" value="{{ item.id }}">
    {{ item.name }}
  </option>
</select>
  `,
  providers: [SOME_SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class SomeSelectComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  private _value: any;

  @Input() optionItems: Array<OptionItem> = [];

  private onTouchedCallback: () => void;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    console.log(obj);
    if (this._value !== obj) {
      this._value = obj;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

}

export interface OptionItem {
  key: String;
  value: String;
}
```

A plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/VNflDbpMm1VmfIHcMcXr?p=preview

Comment: What's the `this.counterValue` in your AppComponent? `object` or `Id(string)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you don't call the **onChangeCallback** when the value is changed:

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="change(select.value)" #select>

change(val) {
  this.onChangeCallback(val);
}
```

Now you can see the control value changed.

The **second** thing that you are missing is update the select box from the model to template, in my plunker I also added the solution.

Working plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/C5mwsDre8OCkWYCDOF4i?p=preview

Comment: Perfect: Thats it

Comment: If it's working, don't forget to accept the answer please.

Comment: That's a good solution, but if you have more than one of the same custom select, it would be a problem since the `#select` id will be the same.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6wX3FiE7pc8nuEbHqFoe?p=preview)

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="writeValue($event.target.value)">
```

An alternative approach

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/V7cjjIElnf5gPUap33Hh?p=preview)

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="_value" (ngModelChange)="writeValue($event)">
<option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Bitte wählen sie einen Eintrag aus aus</option>
```

Comment: Perfect: Thats it

Comment: I like second approach because first doesn't set value in custom component

Comment: That was the idea of the 2nd approach to be able to set the value from the outside.

Comment: It's good idea :) But seems need to call `onChangeCallback` on change event

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker that shows what's not working?

Comment: For me it worked with `<select class="form-control" (change)="writeValue($event.value)">` (without `target`)

Comment: Non of these approaches are working with <mat-select>. Please guide to solve this issue.